# Умножение ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

код например на дельфи

```
var i:integer;//2 байта в памяти
begin
i:=3;
i:=i*i;
i:=i*i;
i:=i*i;
i:=i*i;

.....
//и так сколько угодно могу пока не переполнится
//но переменная всегда будет 2 байта как определил (это же так?)
end
```

А как такое сделать на ассемблере?
если для MUL или IMUL использовать операнды двухбайтовые, то результат будет после первого умножения 4 байта...

Comment: В каноничной форме MUL записывает результат в два регистра, следовательно никогда не переполняется. Однако, при переносе в старший регистр устанавливаются флаг переноса. Таким образом, если переполнение не волнует, достаточно просто игнорировать старший регистр. Со знаковым умножением немного сложнее, необходимо переносить старший бит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В Delphi integer 4-байтный, в ассемблере в 32 битном режиме операнды MUL и IMUL 4-байтные, результат - 8 байтный.
2. Если несколько раз делать i:=i*i; то переменная очень быстро переполнится (т.е. результат будет неверный). Если вам нужно такое же переполнение на ассемблере, просто игнорируйте (обнуляйте) содержимое EDX.
3. Насколько я понял [отсюда](http://asmworld.ru/spravochnik-komand/imul/), у двух-трёхоперандного imul размер результата равен размеру операндов.

Comment: > Delphi integer 4-байтный

Не всегда.

Comment: @karmadro4, возможно, я не очень плотно знаком Delphi. Но предполагаю, что по-умолчанию integer все-таки 32битный.